# Finding all values of $\sin(x - 50^\circ) = -0.682$ between $0^\circ$ and $360^\circ$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

This is probably an easy question, but it stumped me.

To start with I took the inverse both sides, which gave me:

$$\sin(x-50^\circ) = -0.682\\x-50=43^\circ\\x = 7^\circ$$

Now, as I would with any other question like this, I looked at this result on a sine graph and figured that if there's a result at $x=7^\circ$ there should be another solution at $x=173^\circ$ $(180 - 7)^\circ$, because of the periodic nature of the sine graph.

However this is not the case. Can anyone explain why this is the case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The sine is shifted by 50 degrees.

Comment: @MartijnPot Thankyou.  That would make sense, adding 50 to my original answer would give me the correct answer, 223.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is true that:
$$\sin\theta=\sin(180^\circ-\theta)$$
As you got:
$$\sin(7-50)^\circ=\sin (-43^\circ)=-0.682$$
So, other solution should be actually:
$$\sin (-43^\circ)=\sin (180-(-43))^\circ=\sin(223)^\circ$$
**You're confusing x with the argument of sine.**

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @JamesWilliams After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin(x-50^\circ) = -0.682 = \sin(-43^\circ) = \sin(223^\circ) \to x = 7^\circ, 273^\circ. $$